# Achieving clock synchronization via 1588V2

Tags: ethernet, network

Is it possible to achieve **frequency** synchronization between 2 network points (not TOD but actual frequency) - by using 1588V2 alone ?
Or do we have to use SyncE for that ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given that *IEEE 1588-2008* aka *PTP v2* can theoretically provide nanosecond precision, you should be able to synchronize frequencies up to that point as well.

Comment: So doesn't that make SyncE obsolete ?
Or in other words - If my system already implements PTP how would I benefit from combining PTP with SyncE ?

Comment: That depends on the use case and the requirements. SyncE uses lower-layer signaling (L2) and is primarily intended for clock *distribution* across an entire network. PTP can run as overlay since it uses UDP (L4) and is intended for *synchronizing* the time on some nodes.